# What select statement do I use to reference the two foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `Airport` (
    `AirportId` INT (10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`CityId` INT (10) NOT NULL
    ,`AirportName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`AirportId`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 5 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1

INSERT Airport ()
VALUES ('1','1','Belfast City')
    ,('2','1','Belfast International')
    ,('3','2','Gatwick')
    ,('4','2','Stanstead');

CREATE TABLE `Flight` (
    `FlightId` INT (10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`DepartureAirportId` INT (10) NOT NULL
    ,`ArrivalAirportId` INT (10) NOT NULL
    ,`DateLeaving` DATE NOT NULL
    ,`DateReturning` DATE DEFAULT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`FlightId`)
    ,KEY `DepartureAirportId`(`DepartureAirportId`)
    ,KEY `ArrivalAirportId`(`ArrivalAirportId`)
    ,CONSTRAINT `FlightTest_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ArrivalAirportId`) REFERENCES `Airport`(`AirportId`)
    ,CONSTRAINT `FlightTest_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`DepartureAirportId`) REFERENCES `Airport`(`AirportId`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1

INSERT Flight ()
VALUES ('1','1','4','2016-12-04','2016-12-10');
```

I want to use one select statement to view the Airport Name of the Departure and Arrival Airport for that flight.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hint:  You need two `JOIN`s.  What have you tried?

Comment: Try and come back here if you dont understand it

Comment: Fragment revised and code formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT departure.AirportName, arrival.AirportName
FROM Flight
JOIN Airport departure
ON Flight.DepartureAirportId = departure.AirportId
JOIN Airport arrival
ON Flight.ArrivalAirportId = arrival.AirportId
WHERE Flight.FlightId = '1'
```

Effectively what needs to happen here, is joining the Flight table onto the Airport table twice. The key (indeed) in this case, is to join them ON the relevant foreign key within the flight table.

So in order to obtain the relevant airport name for both of them, you need to join each of the foreign keys in the Flight table onto the primary key of the Airport table.

I hope the alias of the two joins being "departure" and "arrival" helps. If not, let me know in the comments how I can clarify better what's happening.

Comment: Thanks very much, problem sorted

Comment: Glad it helped. Please do feel free to mark the question as answered by clicking the tick mark at the left of the answer. :)